# how to make '!tree' work after '!pip install tree' on google colab notebook?

Tags: python, tree, google-colaboratory

I did `!pip install tree` on google colab notebook. It showed that `Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tree) (4.3.0)`. But when I use `!tree`. The notebook reminded me that `bin/bash: tree: command not found`. How to solve it?

I tried several times but all failed.

It showed:

```
Collecting tree
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/3f/63cbed2909786f0e5ac30a4ae5791ad597c6b5fec7167e161c55bba511ce/Tree-0.2.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tree) (4.3.0)
Collecting svgwrite (from tree)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/ce/3259f75aebb12d8c7dd9e8c479ad4968db5ed18e03f24ee4f6be9d9aed23/svgwrite-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 23.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tree) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tree) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from Pillow->tree) (0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from svgwrite->tree) (2.4.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: tree
  Building wheel for tree (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c7/08/aa/42261411808c634cd1d0e9fe6cde5e78bf47c2c8028f3930af
Successfully built tree
Installing collected packages: svgwrite, tree
Successfully installed svgwrite-1.2.1 tree-0.2.4

!pip install tree
!tree
```

I expect it shows the structure of the files in the directory.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to have confused pip with the local package manager?

`!apt-get install tree` does what you want:

```
.
└── sample_data
    ├── anscombe.json
    ├── california_housing_test.csv
    ├── california_housing_train.csv
    ├── mnist_test.csv
    ├── mnist_train_small.csv
    └── README.md

1 directory, 6 files
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed the wrong tree with pip https://pypi.org/project/Tree/

The right code for installation on Mac is `brew install tree`

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

the command for Debian / Ubuntu Linux / Mint is `sudo apt install tree`

Comment: You should mention that your solution is only valid for a specific OS (which uses the brew package manager).

Answer (score 0):

also, it's doesn't work for me but here is an alternative code  for the tree dictionary

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/sample_data'):
  print (path)
  for f in files:
    print (f)
```

[image]